# Relay denied (454)

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server

I make test with the website mxtoolbox.com with my smtp and received this error:

```
220 hostname.example.com ESMTP [702 ms]
EHLO MXTB-PWS3.mxtoolbox.com
250-mail.example.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 20480000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN [671 ms]
MAIL FROM: supertool@mxtoolbox.com 
250 2.1.0 Ok [671 ms]
RCPT TO: test@example.com
454 4.7.1 test@example.com: Relay access denied [671 ms]
```

This is my postfix file **master.cf**:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the Postfix master(5) manual page.
#
# ***** Unused items removed *****
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd

#  -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:127.0.0.1:10024
#  -o receive_override_options=no_address_mappings
pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
  -o content_filter=
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o fallback_relay=
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
#
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
# ====================================================================
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=foo argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient
#
# spam/virus section
#
smtp-amavis  unix  -    -       y       -       2       smtp
  -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
  -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
  -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n  -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
  -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
  -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
  -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
  -o smtpd_helo_required=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
  -o disable_vrfy_command=no
  -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
#
# Dovecot LDA
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:mail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
#
# Vacation mail
vacation    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Rq user=vacation argv=/var/spool/vacation/vacation.pl -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}
```

This is my **main.cf**:

```
# postfix config file

# uncomment for debugging if needed
soft_bounce=yes

# postfix main
mail_owner = postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
delay_warning_time = 4

# postfix paths
html_directory = no
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.2.2/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.2.2/README_FILES

# network settings
inet_interfaces = all
mydomain = hostname.example.com
myhostname = hostname.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.1, MY.ADRESS.SERVER.IP
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost
relay_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/sentora/configs/postfix/mysql-relay_domains_maps.cf

# mail delivery
recipient_delimiter = +

# mappings
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
#local_recipient_maps =

# virtual setup
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/sentora/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_alias_maps.cf,
                     regexp:/etc/sentora/configs/postfix/virtual_regexp
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/sentora/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/sentora/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/sentora/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 998
virtual_uid_maps = static:998
virtual_gid_maps = static:12
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

# debugging
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

# authentication
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth

# tls config
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:$data_directory/smtp_tls_session_cache
# Change mail.example.com.* to your host name
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/tls/private/myhostname.example.com.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/tls/certs/myhostname.example.com.crt
# smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/root.crt

# rules restrictions
smtpd_client_restrictions =
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_unauth_destination,
#        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
#        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
#        reject_unknown_recipient_domain
# uncomment for realtime black list checks. (Warn: will also reject false positive)
#       ,reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org
#       ,reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
#       ,reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net

smtpd_helo_required = yes
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP

message_size_limit = 20480000
```

where myhostname.example.com is my real smtp domain.

I do not know if it's because of this error, but I can not send emails to @outlook or @hotmail accounts

Comment: Dumping an error and your entire mail system configuration on us and expecting us to basically *be* your system administrator is a bit out of scope for Server Fault. I suggest you google `Postfix "relay access denied"` as a starting point, perform some testing on your own, and see if you can work out a solution (or at least narrow the scope of your problem to something that could reasonably be answered in Q&A form as opposed to being a consulting job).

Answer (score 1):

Is your domain (which from SMTP transcript seems to be `example.com` in `proxy:mysql:/etc/sentora/configs/postfix/mysql-relay_domains_maps.cf`?
Because your `mydestination`, which could lead to the mail being accepted, only includes localhost.hostname.domain.com and localhost.

Edit: i was not trying to tell you to add the domain in the mydestination list. Since half your configuration is done via mysql, it's really hard to tell. You can check those tables. I suggest 
checking especially `virtual_mailbox_domains` and `relay_domains`.

You could `debug_peer_list` configuration variable to check what is going on. Maybe that'll hint you in the right direction.

**BUT** I strongly advise against messing with a mailserver, not knowing what you are doing. It is very easy to open up an open relay and get in trouble with your ISP.

btw. you wiped your domains from the whole question, but left it in the very first line of SMTP transcript ;)

btw2. before messing with it even more

Comment: did not work .. put like this:

relay_domains = $mydestination

Comment: Well, we set up the server with the help of tutorials. Unfortunately I do not understand it very linux, then as you said, is not good move where not understand ...